# Generate new arrays from array with objects with specific id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ramda.js

We're using ramda in our project and I do have this data structures and I need to do following thing:

For each set check if the `submittedCheckboxes` are within it and isolate them to new array so I can know if the `valid_amount` amount of checkboxes set to `true` isn't exceeded.

In example below it should throw error indicating id of set #1, as the two of `submittedCheckboxes` have `value: true` where the set specifies `valid_amount: [1]`, but set #2 should be fine as the valid_amount options are either 1 or 2, (`valid_amount: [1,2]`).
The last set should accept every amount of checked checkboxes belonging to it.

```
const sets = [
  {id: 1, checkboxes: [{id: 10}, {id: 20}], valid_amount: [1]},
  {id: 2, checkboxes: [{id: 30}, {id: 40}], valid_amount: [1,2]},
  {id: 3, checkboxes: [{id: 50}, {id: 60}, {id: 70}, {id: 80}], valid_amount: [1,2,3,4]},
];

const submittedCheckboxes = [
  {id: 10, value: true},
  {id: 20, value: true},
  {id: 30, value: true},
  {id: 40, value: true},
  {id: 50, value: true},
  {id: 60, value: false},
  {id: 70, value: true},
  {id: 80, value: false},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const sets = [
 {id: 1, checkboxes: [{id: 10}, {id: 20}], valid_amount: [1]},
 {id: 2, checkboxes: [{id: 30}, {id: 40}], valid_amount: [1,2]},
 {id: 3, checkboxes: [{id: 50}, {id: 60}, {id: 70}, {id: 80}], valid_amount: [1,2,3,4]},
];

const submittedCheckboxes = [
 {id: 10, value: true},
 {id: 20, value: true},
 {id: 30, value: true},
 {id: 40, value: true},
 {id: 50, value: true},
 {id: 60, value: false},
 {id: 70, value: true},
 {id: 80, value: false},
];
console.log(sets.map(valid));

function valid(set) {
 return set.valid_amount.includes(set.checkboxes.filter(checkbox => submittedCheckboxes.find(set=>set.id === checkbox.id).value).length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make sense to reprocess your data first:

**Set**

1. `checkboxes` don’t need to be a list of objects (e.g. `[{id:1},{id:2}]`). It can simply be a list of ids (e.g. `[1,2]`)
2. I’m not sure there’s much point in listing all accepted amounts. Just specify the maximum value each amount can have

So transform:

```
{id: 2, checkboxes: [{id: 30}, {id: 40}], valid_amount: [1,2]},
```

into:

```
{id: 2, checkboxes: [30, 40], max_amount: 2}
```

Here’s a function for it:

```
const transformSet = set => ({
  id: set.id,
  checkboxes: map(prop('id'), set.checkboxes),
  max_amount: last(set.valid_amount)
});
```

**Checkboxes**

It seems (correct me if I’m wrong) that you only care about the objects for which `value` is set to `true`. In this case I’d would remove those for which `value` is set to `false` and keep only the ids.

So transform

```
[
  {id: 10, value: true},
  {id: 20, value: true},
  {id: 30, value: true},
  {id: 40, value: true},
  {id: 50, value: true},
  {id: 60, value: false},
  {id: 70, value: true},
  {id: 80, value: false},
]
```

into:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 70]
```

Here’s a function for it:

```
const transformCheckboxes = into([], compose(
  reject(propEq('value', false)),
  map(prop('id'))
));
```

**Why?**

Let’s take set #1, finding whether an answer has been submitted can be as simple as finding the intersection of two arrays:

intersection([10, 20], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 70])
//=> [10, 20]

Then you need to make sure that the length of the array isn’t greater than the maximum amount for that set:

```
const selectCheckboxes = curry((checkboxes, set) =>
  pipe(intersection, length, gte(set.max_amount))
   (set.checkboxes, checkboxes));
```

Now you can iterate over your sets and you return the first set for which `selectCheckboxes` doesn’t return true. (Notice the use of `complement(selectCheckboxes)`:

```
const findError = useWith(find, [
  compose(complement(selectCheckboxes), transformCheckboxes),
  map(transformSet)]);
```

```js
const {curry, into, intersection, length, gte, map, prop, reject, last, useWith, find, compose, propEq, complement, pipe} = R;

const sets = [
  {id: 1, checkboxes: [{id: 10}, {id: 20}], valid_amount: [1]},
  {id: 2, checkboxes: [{id: 30}, {id: 40}], valid_amount: [1,2]},
  {id: 3, checkboxes: [{id: 50}, {id: 60}, {id: 70}, {id: 80}], valid_amount: [1,2,3,4]},
];

const submittedCheckboxes = [
  {id: 10, value: true},
  {id: 20, value: true},
  {id: 30, value: true},
  {id: 40, value: true},
  {id: 50, value: true},
  {id: 60, value: false},
  {id: 70, value: true},
  {id: 80, value: false},
];

const transformSet = set => ({
  id: set.id,
  checkboxes: map(prop('id'), set.checkboxes),
  max_amount: last(set.valid_amount)
});

const transformCheckboxes = into([], compose(
  reject(propEq('value', false)),
  map(prop('id'))
));


const selectCheckboxes = curry((checkboxes, set) =>
  pipe(intersection, length, gte(set.max_amount))
   (set.checkboxes, checkboxes));


const findError = useWith(find, [
  compose(complement(selectCheckboxes), transformCheckboxes),
  map(transformSet)]);

console.log(

  findError(submittedCheckboxes, sets)
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```